# proof that 1/2 = -1/2

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, infinity, fake-proofs

**Part One:**

S = 1+1+1+1+1+...

1/2 = 1-1+1-1+1-1+...   *if you don't understand, google grandi's series

S - 1/2 = 2+2+2+...

S - 1/2 = 2S

S = -1/2

**Part Two:**

S = 1+1+1+1+...

1/2 = 1-1+1-1+1...

S + 1/2 = 2+2+2+...

S + 1/2 = 2S

S = 1/2

**Conclusions:**

1/2 = -1/2

Can you find the mistake?

Comment: The things you manipulate are not defined. $S$ is not a number (is not even well-defined), since the sum does not converge; yet you manipulate it as if it were one. In short, this is nonsense from line one.

Comment: From [Grandi's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series): "*It is a* ***divergent series***, *meaning that it lacks a sum in the usual sense. On the other hand, its Cesàro sum is 1/2*". Do you know what a Cesaro sum is, and the rules for manipulating Cesaro summable series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the series
$$S = 1 + 1 + 1 + ... $$
and
$$G = 1 - 1 + 1-1+...$$
are **divergent**, and hence you cannot apply normal algebraic manipulations on them. For example Grandi's series $G$ does *not* equal $1/2$ in the normal sense, but through something called Cesàro summation.

Comment: Then how do we know that 1-1+1-1+... = 1/2? That can be proved using algebraic manipulation.

Comment: "Then how do we know that $1-1+1-1+... = 1/2$?" Well, im sorry to tell you, but you've been mislead. It is simply not true in the usual sense of equality.

Comment: So all the algebraic proofs of this are coincidental? For example:                                       S = 1-1+1-1+...                                                                                                    1-S=S                                                                                                         S=1/2?

Comment: We do not know that $1-1+1-...=1/2$.  We know that $1-x+x^2-...$ has a limit of $1/2$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from one direction, which is whar Cesaro summation is.  Limit convergence approaching a point and equality at the point are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: Did Ramanujan use Cesaro Summation to prove that 1+2+3+4+... = -1/12?

Comment: Again, this equality is not what you think it is. It is only true in some very [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Ramanujan_summation) [senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Zeta_function_regularization), which are **not** the usual equality you are thinking of, and certainly do **not** mean that the sum converges in the usual sense.